# conditionally set width of modal depending on props passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, modal-dialog

I am trying to set the width of a modal that is being animated on enter and leave using ReactCSSTransitionGroup. I am creating a modal in `Modal` and rendering its children. I need to conditionally set the className 'ui-modal' to either be 'ui-modal-small' or 'ui-modal-large' depending on what this.props.size is. I am hitting an issue where I only successfully can get this.props.size value in `UiModal`, I can't seem to get the value in `Modal`, where I would be doing a conditional render for being able to set the CSS depending on the size (something like: `this.props.size === 'large' ? 'ui-modal-large' : 'ui-modal-small'`). Here are both components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import '../../modal.css';

const Modal = React.createClass({
    render(){
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            return (
              <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={400} transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>
               <div className="ui-modal" key={this.props.transitionName}> 
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            );
        } else {
            return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} />;
        }
    }
});

const UiModal = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return { isModalOpen: false };
    },

    openModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    },

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
    },

    setModalSize() {
        this.setState({ isModalLarge: false });
    },

    render() {
        const { openBtnText, header, subHeader, body, footer, optionalFooterText, closeBtnText, size } = this.props;
        return (
          <div className="ui-modal-trigger-container">
            <h1>Modal small enter from bottom</h1>
            <div className="button" onClick={this.openModal}>{ this.props.openBtnText }</div>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim">
              <h1 className="ui-modal-header">{header}</h1>
              <div className="ui-modal-subheader">{subHeader}</div>
              <div className="ui-modal-body">
                {body}
              </div>
              <div className="ui-modal-footer">
                <div className="ui-modal-footer-button-group">
                  <div className="ui-modal-footer-button button" onClick={this.closeModal}>{closeBtnText}</div>
                  <div className="ui-modal-optional-footer-text" onClick={this.closeModal}>{optionalFooterText}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

export default UiModal;
```

Below: calling the uiModal component with the following props:

```
 <UiModal 
    openBtnText={'open me'}
    header={'UiModal Header'}
    body={'This is a modal body'}
    subHeader={'This is a modal subheader'}
    closeBtnText={'close me'}
    size={'small'}
    optionalFooterText={'this is optional text+'}
   />
```

Comment: I don't see a `const` statement in that component.  How are you pulling `size` in to the Modal component?

Comment: when I try to get this.props.size in Modal it is coming back undefined. I have tried adding const {size} = this.props and it doesn't seem accessible in Modal.

Comment: What does the call to your Modal component look like?

Comment: Adding to original question ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to add the conditional statement to your modal components render method and then use the derived value where required. e.g.

```
render() {
    const { openBtnText, header, subHeader, body, footer, optionalFooterText, closeBtnText, size } = this.props;

    const modalSize = size === 'large' ? 'ui-modal-large' : 'ui-modal-small';

    return (
      <div className={"ui-modal-trigger-container " + modalSize}>
        <h1>Modal small enter from bottom</h1>
        <div className="button" onClick={this.openModal}>{ this.props.openBtnText }</div>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim" size={modalSize}>
          <h1 className="ui-modal-header">{header}</h1>
          <div className="ui-modal-subheader">{subHeader}</div>
          <div className="ui-modal-body">
            {body}
          </div>
          <div className="ui-modal-footer">
            <div className="ui-modal-footer-button-group">
              <div className="ui-modal-footer-button button" onClick={this.closeModal}>{closeBtnText}</div>
              <div className="ui-modal-optional-footer-text" onClick={this.closeModal}>{optionalFooterText}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
}
});

export default UiModal;
```

and then in your Modal component

```
const Modal = React.createClass({
    render(){
        // Use size wherever you need.
        const size = this.props.size;
        if(this.props.isOpen){
            return (
              <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={400} transitionLeaveTimeout={400}>
               <div className="ui-modal" key={this.props.transitionName}> 
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            );
        } else {
            return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} />;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for you help - the `trigger-container` isn't the actual modal (its just the button to trigger the modal to open)- I would need attach the said className to <Modal /> somehow which is only giving me errors. The className to set the width of the modal in the current implementation is 'ui-modal' in `Modal`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to pass the size as a prop to the Modal. What are the errors you are getting? You should be passing the size prop to the Modal like so -  `<Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim" size={size}>`.

Comment: I have applied the above, `size={size}` to `Modal` and its not actually applying a className at all.. I am still getting just 'ui-modal' which is given in the `Modal` copmonent, not UiModal. Its not actually changing the ui-modal className here: `<div className="ui-modal" key={this.props.transitionName}> 
                  {this.props.children}
                </div>
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>`

Comment: In your Modal component, you need - `const size = this.props.size;` Then use the constant wherever you need to apply the CSS class name.

Comment: When I have attempted to do that in `Modal`, this.props.size comes back undefined. When I get this.props.size in `UiModal` it comes back perfectly.